# Breaking dependencies on remote APIs

Tags: rest, api, dependencies, mocking

The system I'm working on has a core web application where the bulk of the work is done. However, it relies on another server to handle transactional finance data. It connects to the server using a REST API. I'm trying to work only on the core web application but I keep hitting pages and function calls that rely on the REST API.

For getting up and running, I was told that the best option is to connect to the VPN and to point the API client to the shared REST API server.

While that's a reasonable solution for a quick bug fix or QA, I feel that it isn't very good for the application in general. This massive dependency makes it hard to test and develop but I don't know how to break it.

What are my options?

Should I be mocking out all the API client calls? Should I be using mocks and patches only when I'm fixing something? Or should I just suck it up and use the VPN and shared REST API server?

Comment: There's a real benefit to mocking out all the API client calls. Just think of all the automated testing you can do while you sit back. Make a change, run your tests, and verify that everything is still working properly. Ever since I mocked out a large project at work that relied heavily on a database, I've been so much more at ease making even minor changes that might have broken everything before (and silently, too).

Comment: @mgw854 I'm already mocking things out for unit tests, I'm mainly wondering if I should have mocks when I'm manually testing frontend-related changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two approaches I've seen are as follows:

1. **Duplicate the dependency in a Development environment**.

   - This clearly requires more resources, and can be a hassle when it comes to keeping your environments in sync, but it's as representative of Production as you can get.
   - All you have to change is the endpoint of your REST API dependency.
2. **Create a dependency Mock you can use when debugging**

   - This is an option I've used when it simply wasn't possible to create a Dev environment representative of Production.  It will require writing a mock of your own, but, depending on the complexity of your scenarios, might not actually be much work.
   - If you like building manual testing tools, this can be a lot of fun.  It also makes demos a bit more interesting!

Not much else to say, really :)